# Integrate twitter and facebook with phonegap using only javascript

Tags: facebook, cordova, twitter

Is there possibility to integrate twitter and facebook with phonegap using only javascript? The reason behind to use javascript is application can run on different platforms i-e it can run on ios,blackberry,symbian,android and webos.

need an idea ....

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you [attempted](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms) searching for [examples](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)?

Comment: yes .. but still hopeless

Comment: If it's hopeless, then I suggest a different hobby/profession than programming.

Comment: hahah it will be worthy if there is any solution

Comment: Perhaps you can develop a solution and share with the community? In essence, yes you can do it Javascript only. But you will need to use Oauth and the InAppBrowser plugin from PhoneGap. There are a couple of plugins/blogs out there that can help you out. Just hit Google.

Comment: still googling :( but didn't find any good solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this social sharing cordova plugin.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin